# LINDO Non linear programming - Modlus and square operation

Tags: lindo

I tried this
MIN 0.2 [ 2 + @ABS( 2x^2+2x-3) +  @ABS( 2x^3+5x-2) +  @ABS( 2x^4+2x^3+5x^2+7x-2.5) ]

For the equation

min 0.2[2+|2x^2+2x-3| + |2x^3+5x-2| +  |2x^4+2x^3+5x^2+7x-2.5|]

But getting error

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem in the way of writing the script of the equation.

so, I tried this and I got the solution.

MIN = 0.2*( 2 + @ABS( 2*x^2+2*x-3) + @ABS( 2*x^3+5*(x-2)) + @ABS( 2*x^4+2*x^3+5*x^2+7*(x-2.5)));